# How to convert polyline or polygon into chain-code?

Tags: algorithm, polygon, vector-graphics, polyline, rasterizing

I have an open or closed polyline (polygon) consisted from the set of 2D points.

I need to represent that polyline as a chain-code. If I correctly understand, I need to rasterize polyline segments using Bresenham's algorithm and construct chain-code form that raster. But is there a better algorithm?

What is the optimal algorithms for converting polyline (polygon) into chain-code?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it will be significantly faster to simply draw the points directly into the Fourier transform. Skip the raster and making a chaincode from that, after all you need the points correctly in order in the direction the polyline takes for what I assume is Kuhl-Giardiana 1982 algorithmic use. You want all the pixels in the correct order, you can directly get that by drawing the pixels into the algorithm itself rather than rasterizing anything. In fact, this would basically skip the chain code and the raster.

---

All lines are going to be of the form y = mx+b and the fastest way to do this is going to be Bresenham's. Though, depending on the eventual use you might opt for Wu's algorithm so that you can be sure to include anti-aliasing, which tends to make the lines look sharper (and requires you save the alpha). Assuming you need the chain code for something specific, yes you need the actual pixels that that line will produce which means using a line drawing algorithm.

Most of your drawing apis will give you the rasterized image rather than chain-code. There is the option of drawing the polyline on to an aptly sized white image in black and going through the entire image and listing every black pixel. It would be easy to code, though slow and unneeded and in mission critical operations would be a non-starter.

The code is going to be pretty easy, just do bresenham and then toss the points where it would add a point into the chaincode.

```
public void plotLines(int[] twodshape, Chaincode chain) {
    for (int i = 0, s = twodshape.length-4; i < s; i+=2) {
        plotLine(twodshape[i],twodshape[i+1],twodshape[i+2],twodshape[i+3],chain);
    }
}
public void plotLine(int x0, int y0, int x1, int y1, Chaincode chain) {

    int dy = y1 - y0; //BRESENHAM LINE DRAW ALGORITHM
    int dx = x1 - x0;

    int stepx, stepy;

    if (dy < 0) {
        dy = -dy;
        stepy = -1;
    } else {
        stepy = 1;
    }

    if (dx < 0) {
        dx = -dx;
        stepx = -1;
    } else {
        stepx = 1;
    }
    if (dx > dy) {
        dy <<= 1;                                                  // dy is now 2*dy
        dx <<= 1;
        int fraction = dy - (dx >> 1);                         // same as 2*dy - dx
        chain.add(x0,y0);

        while (x0 != x1) {
            if (fraction >= 0) {
                y0 += stepy;
                fraction -= dx;                                // same as fraction -= 2*dx
            }
            x0 += stepx;
            fraction += dy;                                    // same as fraction += 2*dy
            chain.add(x0,y0);
        }
        chain.add(x0,y0);
    } else {
        dy <<= 1;                                                  // dy is now 2*dy
        dx <<= 1;                                                  // dx is now 2*dx
        int fraction = dx - (dy >> 1);
        chain.add(x0,y0);
        while (y0 != y1) {
            if (fraction >= 0) {
                x0 += stepx;
                fraction -= dy;
            }
            y0 += stepy;
            fraction += dx;
            chain.add(x0,y0);
        }
        chain.add(x0,y0);
    }
}
```

Update:
I removed the recursive bit, I needed that for a specific issue with lines being drawn from point A to point B not being guaranteed to be the same from B to A. Due to the rounding of the slope. For example if you are going up 1 pixel and right 5. There are two equally valid ways of doing this, and it wasn't giving me a consistent answer.

---

If you deeply need it in chaincode:

```
public int convertToChaincode(int cx, int cy) {
    if ((cx == 1) && (cy == 0)) return 0;
    if ((cx == 1) && (cy == 1)) return 1;
    if ((cx == 0) && (cy == 1)) return 2;
    if ((cx == -1) && (cy == 1)) return 3;
    if ((cx == -1) && (cy == 0)) return 4;
    if ((cx == -1) && (cy == -1)) return 5;
    if ((cx == 0) && (cy == -1)) return 6;
    if ((cx == 1) && (cy == -1)) return 7;
    return -1; //error.
}

public void plotLine(int x0, int y0, int x1, int y1, ChainCode chain) {

    int dy = y1 - y0; //BRESENHAM LINE DRAW ALGORITHM
    int dx = x1 - x0;

    int stepx, stepy;
    int cx = 0;
    int cy = 0;

    if (dy < 0) {
        dy = -dy;
        stepy = -1;
    } else {
        stepy = 1;
    }

    if (dx < 0) {
        dx = -dx;
        stepx = -1;
    } else {
        stepx = 1;
    }
    if (dx > dy) {
        dy <<= 1;                                                  // dy is now 2*dy
        dx <<= 1;
        int fraction = dy - (dx >> 1);                         // same as 2*dy - dx
        //typically set start point.

        while (x0 != x1) {
            if (fraction >= 0) {
                y0 += stepy;
                cy = stepy;
                fraction -= dx;                                // same as fraction -= 2*dx
            }
            x0 += stepx;
            cx = stepx;
            fraction += dy;                                    // same as fraction += 2*dy
            chain.add(convertToChaincode(cx,cy));
        }
    } else {
        dy <<= 1;                                                  // dy is now 2*dy
        dx <<= 1;                                                  // dx is now 2*dx
        int fraction = dx - (dy >> 1);
        //typically set start point
        while (y0 != y1) {
            if (fraction >= 0) {
                x0 += stepx;
                cx = stepx;
                fraction -= dy;
            }
            y0 += stepy;
            cy = stepy;
            fraction += dx;
            chain.add(convertToChaincode(cx,cy));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I need a chain-code to make an Elliptic Fourier Transform of the outline (the polygon).

Comment: You have the polygon itself, I suppose if you want it curvier but there seems to be other ways to do that. But, whatever, there's the code. Doing it that way with the class could maybe even let you skip the chaincode part of your current idea. You could have the line draw algorithm feed those points into the FFT.

Comment: Ah, Kuhl-Giardina's thing and likely for machine learning of some variety. To be fair I had this code at hand because I too do something with the actual pixels in polylines so have at. Best of luck.